# Show that $X$ is compact if and only if $X_{r}$ is compact for all $r \in $ {$1, ..., n$}.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Let $X_{1}, X_{2}, ..., X_{n}$ be subsets of $\mathbb{R^m}$ and $X = X_{1} \times X_{2} \times ... \times X_{n}$. Show that $X$ is compact if and only if $X_{r}$ is compact for all $r \in $ {$1, ..., n$}.

What I've done:

Let $X$ be compact, then $X$ is closed and bounded. Now because of how $X$ is defined then $X_{1}, X_{2}, ..., X_{n}$ are closed and bounded subsets, so $X_{r}$ will be compact for all $r \in$ {$1,..., n$}

That would be the departure, can someone help me with the return and tell me if the departure is okay?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am just giving you hints
If part :$X_{i}$ is compact for all $i=1,2,..,n$ then trivially Metric $X$ is compact.
For only if part: Assume some $X_{j}$ is not compact for some $j$ where $j$ is in naturals. Then show that $X$ is not compact.
Cheers!!!